# SQL Server UNION multiple selects in a WHILE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a WHILE statement in a stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @reverseindex int
DECLARE @index INT

SET @index = 1

WHILE (@index <= @workingyears)
BEGIN
    SET @reverseindex = @workingyears-@index+1

    SELECT daysallowed, date, holidaytype, leavetype, isactive 
    FROM setup_holiday_schedule 
    WHERE workingyears = @reverseindex
      AND holidayschedulecode = @holidayschedulecode
END
```

Running this query I get multiple tables depending on how big is `@workingyears`. I would like at the end of the WHILE statement to have just one table result.

Is that possible?

Comment: I assume that you don't want to just select where workingyears between 1 and @workingyears and order by workingyears desc.  Right?

Comment: Exactly, I want to leave the WHILE statement, this is just an example-

Comment: You could create a temp table, insert into it during the `while` loop, and then select from it at the end.

Comment: Yes i think temp table is the right solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a table-valued variable?

```
DECLARE @reverseindex int
DECLARE @index INT
DECLARE @results TABLE (
    daysallowed INT,
    date DATE,
    holidaytype INT,
    leavetype INT,
    isactive BIT
)

SET @index = 1
WHILE (@index <= @workingyears)
BEGIN

    SET @reverseindex = @workingyears-@index+1
    INSERT INTO @results (
        daysallowed, date, holidaytype, leavetype, isactive
    )
    SELECT daysallowed, date, holidaytype, leavetype, isactive 
    FROM setup_holiday_schedule 
    WHERE workingyears = @reverseindex
    AND holidayschedulecode = @holidayschedulecode

END

SELECT daysallowed, date, holidaytype, leavetype, isactive FROM @results
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a `while` function at all?  I think this query does pretty much the same thing:

```
SELECT daysallowed, date, holidaytype, leavetype, isactive 
FROM setup_holiday_schedule 
WHERE workingyears between 1 and @workingyears AND
      holidayschedulecode = @holidayschedulecode
ORDER BY workingyears desc;
```